# bootstrap typeahead prevent default selection

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, preventdefault, bootstrap-typeahead

Can I prevent bootstrap typeahead from populating/clearing the element?

Here is an example [bootply.com/79110](http://bootply.com/79110)

Notice how I am updating the element with my own code. When the alert appears you will see that it works but then the element value gets deleted. I want to prevent the typeahead from updating the element.

Comment: Could you provide a demo? http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead and http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ seem to behave similarly

Comment: Yes, the demo please. The following is hard to understand without some example or further explanation: '... populating the input with the item?'

Comment: Hi @Neil i have added a demo and clarified my question. Please help :)

Comment: Hi @MichaelFreake - I have added a demo and clarified my question.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the `updater` function returns the item..

```
updater: function (item) {
     /* do whatever you want with the selected item */
     return item;
},
```

So, if you do not have the `updater` function return the item, the input will not be set..

```
updater: function (item) {
     /* do whatever you want with the selected item */
    alert("selected "+item);
},
```

<kbd>[**Demo on Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/61459)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Skelly,

Thanks for your example. I forked it to update the input with the item but it does not work http://www.bootply.com/79110